# Convert the Time to GMT and then upload the timestamp to Firebase (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

**What I want to do:** Convert the current time of the user to a GMT timestamp and then upload it to firebase.

**Problem:** The timestamp in my Firestore database is not the GMT timestamp, but the regular one with the unique timezone of the user.

**My code:**

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
let date = Date()
```

```
self.db.collection("posts").document(combined).setData([
    "time": date,
]) { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error writing document: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Post Document successfully written!")
        print(date)
    }
}
```

**What actually happens so far:**
I get `2020-06-26 17:57:40 +0000`when I print out the date after I uploaded to firebase. This is the timestamp I want to upload.

But once I check firebase I see:
[image]

**What I tried:**

- Deleting the app and installing it once again
- Clearing my firebase Firestore

Comment: The GCP console is converting your UTC date to your local date, for example try to crete a new test entity. Add a property of type "Date and Time" select a date and time with GTM/UTC as time zone. Add Another property, at this point the card of the first property will be collapsed and should show the previous property value in Local time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two timestamps are actually the same. i.e. 19:57:40 in UTC+2 is the same as 17:57:40 in UTC+0.

So I suspect the issue is what's actually being displayed in the Firebase console. There's likely a setting somewhere that controls how dates are displayed.

Comment: There is actually not a setting.  The console always uses what the local computer's timezone is set to.

Comment: Okay thank you. I was worried that I didn't do something correct.